# Do manual interaction in nunit tests?

Tags: c#, nunit

I am using Nunit from C# and .NET Core to do hardware/production testing on some electronics. Test cases are stimulating the hardware in different ways, and as a final check I turn on an LED. This is kind of hard to verify automatically (without building some custom hardware), so I want to have a manual verification step for the user to say pass or fail if the LED is turned on or not. Is this even possible in Nunit?

I have tried using `Console.ReadLine()/Console.ReadKey()` which is not working. Is there some way to make that work or are there any alternatives to this?

The other option I have is to put this manual step outside the Nunit framework, e.g. in a shell script. But then I would lose the benefits of result handling and more. Any recommendations for this?

Comment: I don't think NUnit is good solution here. Simple console app will be suffice for interatction. Better to leave thing as simple as possible - separate your logic to interactive and non-interactive.

Comment: Do you want just a manual "this test was OK/not OK"-option in order to indicate a green or red test? Then don´t rely on NUnit for the result, just execute your console as usual without NUnit.

Comment: @HimBromBeere: yes, basically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure it's possible to hack nuint around, but does this "feature" worth it? I think this will be smelly and cost you/your collegues more resources at support, because no easy workaround here. I suggest you to separate logic in two:

One for semi-automatic (i.e. hand testing) which comes as simple Console application with expert questions and answers (is some LED on/off? spark comes out? powerbank exploded?).

The other for automatic testing (NUnit, ot whatever) as simple dll.

The benefit of this approach, you can run automatic test from semi-automatic console app at some point (probably at start), and you can easly interact with expert.

Answer (score 1):

NUnit does not really work with a console - and in fact you shouldn´t use it to test something that needs user-interaction - which would be an integration-test. Although you could implement it:

```
if(Double.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out var ok) && ok)
    Assert.Pass("Test OK");
else
    Assert.Fail("Test failed");
```

I doubt it´s a good idea as it´s impossible to automate - which is one of the main-goals of unit-tests.

As all you want seems to be some marker for NUnit if or if not your test was successfull, I would just allways use `Assert.Inconclusive` to indicate that a user has to manually interpret the result (e.g. a file) in some way. In fact you can completely ignore NUnit for this type of test, just start your app and let your user use it as usual.

In addition write unit-tests for everything that **is** testable. Refactor your code if neccessary in order to get something testable, which is extracting the business-logic from your UI.

Comment: Thanks! Many unit test frameworks are also good general test frameworks (usable for integration, manual, hardware, etc.. testing). This apparently, is not the case with Nunit, since this "feature" is lacking. I will most likely do some console/shell application that calls the unit test features for the automatic tests, and then implement the manual check separately.

Answer (score 0):

NUnit and other testing frameworks are designed to perform unit testing.

A unit is defind by [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_testing) as

> Unit tests are typically automated tests written and run by software
>   developers to ensure that a section of an application (known as the
>   "unit") meets its design and behaves as intended.

Basically, what you want to do is therefore not a unit test, it is more of an integration test as you want to test if two separate distinct areas of the solution work together, that is the software and the hardware.

Therefore, this is not really what NUnit, or similar unit testing frameworks, were designed to do.

Therefore, use NUnit to test the software part, and then look at other options for the integration testing, which might mean writing other tools or even just doing it manually!

Comment: Thanks. In practice though, what defines a "unit", varies widely. I have worked in 10+ years using different unit-testing frameworks that were designed for smaller units, to do integration tests and hardware tests. This is the first time I am using nunit though.